# How to showing expanding text with javascript and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, expand

i need to make my text expand if i click on "more" and if i click on another "more"class i want to make it so my text retracts from all the other. so basically that there only is one "more"class is expanded. also i wanted to make the text change from more to less if the text div is open.

This is my html code

```
<div class="content_horses" id="page">
    <div class="accordeon" class="een">
        <div class="sientje">
            <img class="photo" src="images/horses/siente.png" alt="sientje"></img>
            <div class="name">
                SIENTJE
            </div>
            <div class="expand">
                <div class="more">MORE</div>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <div class="sientje_t">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="accordeon" class="twee">
        <div class="sientje">
            <img class="photo" src="images/horses/siente.png" alt="sientje"></img>
            <div class="name">
                SIENTJE
            </div>
            <div class="expand">
                <div class="more">MORE</div>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <div class="sientje_t">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

And this is my script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".text").hide();
    $(".expand").click(function() {
        $(this).next(".text").slideToggle(500);
        $(this).text($(this).text() == 'LESS' ? 'MORE' : 'LESS').toggleClass('up');
    });
    $(".expand").click(function() {
       $(".text").slideUp(500);
        if ($(this).next(".text").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).next(".text").slideUp(500);
        } else {
            $(this).next(".text").slideToggle(500);
        }
    });
});
```

I hope you will help me

Comment: Provide a link to JSFiddle.

Comment: what is the problem you are having?  (what works so far and what doesn't?)

Comment: The text of it unfold but collapsed immediately, but the text should stand, and if you're on another 'more' clicks must first pass go back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your script as this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".text").hide();  
  $(".expand").click(function() {
    $(".text").slideUp(500);
    $(".expand").text('MORE');

    if ($(this).next(".text").is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next(".text").slideUp(500);
    } else {
      $(this).next(".text").slideToggle(500);
      $(this).text('LESS');
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/drh8snj5/

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".text").hide();  
    $(".expand").click(function() {
        $(".text").slideUp(500);
        $(".expand").text('MORE');

    if ($(this).next(".text").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next(".text").slideUp(500);
    } else {
        $(this).next(".text").slideDown(500);
        $(this).text('LESS');
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is just not what I want, the 1st block of text should go if you want to read the 2nd block. Ook moet eerst de knop more staan en als je daar op klikt pas less

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle with text that shows and hides:

https://jsfiddle.net/mupfu53p/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.content').each(function() {
    var thisText = $(this).text();
    var shortText = thisText.substring(0, thisText.indexOf(" ", 50)) + '...';
    $(this).data('longText', thisText);
    $(this).data('shortText', shortText);
    $(this).text($(this).data('shortText'));
  });


  $('.more').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisSib = $(this).prev('.content');
    var currentText = $(thisSib).text();

    if (currentText === $(thisSib).data('shortText')) {
      $(thisSib).text($(thisSib).data('longText'));
    } else {

      $(thisSib).text($(thisSib).data('shortText'));

    }
  });

});
```

Not sure if it is what you want but perhaps the other answers are closer.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code below. I Think it will solve your problem.
FYI, html image tag will be like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".text").hide();
  
     $(".expand").click(function() {
       $(".more").html('LESS');
           $(".text").slideUp(500);
            if ($(this).next(".text").is(":visible")) {
                    $(this).next(".text").slideUp(500);
                    $(".more").html('MORE');
            } else {
                    $(this).next(".text").slideToggle(500);
            }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content_horses" id="page">
            <div class="accordeon" class="een">
                <div class="sientje">
                    <img class="photo" src="http://demo.joomlaman.com/jm-palas/images/showcase/bg16.jpg" alt="sientje" />
                    <div class="name">
                        SIENTJE
                    </div>
                    <div class="expand">
                        <div class="more">MORE</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <div class="sientje_t">
TEST1
                          TEST@
                          TEST3
                          TEST4
                          TEST5
                          TEST6
                          TEST7
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="accordeon" class="twee">
                <div class="sientje">
                    <img class="photo" src="http://demo.joomlaman.com/jm-palas/images/showcase/bg16.jpg" alt="sientje" />
                    <div class="name">
                        SIENTJE
                    </div>
                    <div class="expand">
                        <div class="more">MORE</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <div class="sientje_t">
TEST1
                          TEST@
                          TEST3
                          TEST4
                          TEST5
                          TEST6
                          TEST7
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".expand").click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).find('.more').text();
    $('.more').text('MORE');
    $(".text").slideUp(500);
    $(this).next('.text').slideToggle(500);
    $(this).find('.more').text('LESS');
  });
});
```

```css
.expand {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content_horses" id="page">
  <div class="accordeon" class="een">
    <div class="sientje">
      <img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/150" alt="sientje" />
      <div class="name">
        SIENTJE
      </div>
      <div class="expand">
        <div class="more">MORE</div>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="sientje_t">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe optio aperiam, accusamus assumenda! Quidem accusantium, officia, esse ipsam magni nostrum asperiores cum quod itaque, est obcaecati perspiciatis amet alias quia?
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="accordeon" class="twee">
    <div class="sientje">
      <img class="photo" src="http://placehold.it/150" alt="sientje" />
      <div class="name">
        SIENTJE
      </div>
      <div class="expand">
        <div class="more">MORE</div>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="sientje_t">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis animi eum mollitia provident aut cum eos expedita commodi, sunt, quam, odio error. Tempore quasi, tenetur blanditiis debitis deleniti nobis deserunt!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
```